# Habilitar Botón desde otra Clase

Tags: android, android-studio, webservice

Buen día a todos. Mi pregunta es simple, ¿Como puedo habilitar un botón desde otra clase? Les planteo mi problema, tengo mi MainActivity y en ella tengo un boton que realiza una consulta mediante una clase de tipo WebService, este es el código de mi botón.

```
 private View.OnClickListener iniciarSesion = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Aqui ejecuto el WS y desactivo el botón mientras se realiza la consulta.
        WSConsulta.execute();
        btnIniciarSesion.setEnabled(false);
    }
};
```

En la clase del WS dentro del onPostExecute, tengo 2 métodos, uno que envía un un msj satrisfactorio y continua la carga de la app y otro envia un msj de error si la consulta devuelve false, aqui es donde deseo habilitar otra vez mi boton, como puedo hacerlo?

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String ConsultaRespuesta) {
    if(!ConsultaRespuesta.equals("")){
        //Continuo la carga de mi app
    }
    else {
        //msj de error
        //Aqui es donde deseo volver a activar mi botón.
    }
    super.onPostExecute(ConsultaRespuesta);
}
```

por su ayuda gracias

Answer (score 2):

Una opción es crear una interface y utilizarla como un listener.

La interface sería algo como

```
public interface ResponseListener{
   public void onResponseError();
}
```

En tu clase WSConsulta

```
...
 if(!ConsultaRespuesta.equals("")){
     ...
 }else{
     responseListener.onResponseError();
 }
...
```

Puedes crear un setter para recibir una implementación del listener.

```
public void setResponseListener(ResponseListener responseListener){
   this.responseListener = responseListener;
}
```

En tu MainActivity se crea la implementación y se envía a  WSConsulta. Cuando se llame onResponseError habilitas el botón.

```
WSConsulta.setResponseListener(new ResponseListener(){
  @Override
  public void onResponseError(){
      btnIniciarSesion.setEnabled(true);
  } 
});
```